# What is the meaning of “There's baloney in our slacks” (Animaniacs theme song)?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Part of the theme tune of the 1990s cartoon series [Animaniacs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105941/) has these words:

> We're Animaniacs!
>   We have pay-or-play contracts.
>   We're zany to the max
>   There's baloney in our slacks.

I do not understand the meaning of that latter line. What makes matters worse is that some sources indicate that the line contains a double-meaning (innuendo) and I don’t understand that either.

I’m led to understand that *baloney* has two meanings: *nonsense*, and some kind of sausage. *Slack*, furthermore, has many possible meanings.

The on-screen imagery accompanying this line is the following:

[image: There’s baloney in our slacks]

This seems to take the line literally: they throw slices of baloney (the sausage) into Yakko’s slack (the textile oversize). But this makes no sense to me whatsoever.

So, my questions are:

- Why this particular type of sausage, why would anyone want to put sausage in their pants, and why is this funny?
- What is the innuendo/double-meaning that I’m missing?

Comment: Really? you have *zero* idea what the innuendo might be?

Comment: Hm, I guess that if you're thinking dirty on this one, you should consider that for what it's worth there's a girl in the gang, and they clearly say "There's baloney in **our** slacks". Even though she's not wearing a slack, and neither is Wakko...

Comment: @Wyatt Please remember that when people learn a new language, they may understand the literal meaning of a statement, but have difficulty seeing much further than that. At least for me, when I study Spanish I find that occasionally I can parse the meaning of each individual word in a sentence, but get lost when trying to understand the meaning of it as a whole. Furthermore, I know of at least one person for whom English is not her first language, who has told me that she takes longer to "get things" in English as opposed to Spanish, even though she speaks both languages fluently.

Comment: A minor note: it's "into Yakko's slacks" not "into Yakko's slack".  *Slacks* is one of those strange words that's always plural, when it means pants.  (And *pants* is another one that's always plural...)

Comment: The possible innuendo can be discerned simply from the provided illustration.

Comment: @stangdon indeed, but it's curious I heard in a 1950s movie just last night something like *Careful, I have a scissors in my hand*. Not *a scissor*, which you can Google and find instances of  but *a scissors*, so I enjoy the variety of ways English speakers speak.

Comment: @Wyatt It may be possible that in OP's native language it is more unusual to use the image of pork meat in such a suggestive manner. Different languages induce not only different manners of speech/phrasing, but also different patterns of thought, in particular different manners of "thinking dirty". Also of note is that OP is not the only one to struggle with the innuendo here (cf. the other answerer).

Comment: @stangdon https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=slacks%2C%20slack this chart says the use of "slack" surpasses the use of "slacks", mainly in the last years, when it increased a lot

Comment: @JoaoArruda - Yes, but that chart tells you nothing about the meaning or context of "slack".  ["Slack" has many other meanings besides "pants".](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slack)  That's why I said "when it means pants."  I suspect the increase in the usage of "slack" over the last few years has to do with the popularity of [Slack.com](http://slack.com), which makes a tool that is very popular with businesses right now.  [Trust me, when we mean pants, it's "slacks".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wearing+slack%2Cwearing+slacks&year_start=1900&year_end=2000)

Comment: I think it's a dirty joke referring to the excuse you could give when someone asks "Hey!! Is that an erection??"

Answer (score 3):

Considering that the Animaniacs were a bit... Lunatic... I think they're just expressing that they are crazy, to the point of carrying baloney slices in their slacks?

Or maybe its innuendo lies on the fact that *baloney* is a slang for **nonsense** as you stated, and the only piece of cloth the character is wearing is a slack. So, that means they are full of nonsense, so that their clothes are filled with it.

The "funny" bit (if one could say it's funny) lies on the literal visual interpretation of the sentence, which the viewer gets confused as to think "no, it's not possible that this is literal, this HAS to have some hidden message". But they do it literally anyway.

Comment: Not just that, see other answer, but including that, yes, nice way to put it.

Answer (score 2):

In English at least, pork meat is occasionally used to suggest the male member. It is rather crude. Now there is the question of whether the creators had that innuendo in mind. I'm hard-pressed to find a reasonable case that they did not. It seems that they kept it just subtle enough so that there would be no chance that the kiddos would get it, but not much more. That being said, I have not seen a single episode of Animaniacs since I was probably ~10 years old, so this is a real eye-opener for me.

Comment: Bear in mind the show frequently featured innuendo-laden jokes that Yakko would respond to with "Goodnight everybody!", so it's not even remotely beyond possibility that the writers of the theme song knew exactly what they were doing with the baloney line.

Answer (score 0):

When the series director was asked the question directly (about whether this line was literal), he pretty much answered: yes on Monday's, Wednesday's and Friday's (apparently, very specific I know).

But I would not be surprised if its meaning could be interpreted as "sausage inside your pants" (if that makes it more obvious for you), as an innuendo because it is the type of joke that the Animaniacs would totally make.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they mean the dick because Saussure can mean weiner so it seems like they mean They mean “There’s A dick in our slacks “